# PHP Legacy Code: mysqli for/while loops

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, mysqli

Updating some extremely old legacy PHP code that I didn't write to start with so that it works with 5.6.30 and running into some issues with some of the old for/while loops.  This stuff works great on old PHP, but the while/for loop blows up in the ($link, $contributor_results, $j) section since I've got too many $s

Yes, a fairly basic n00b question, but not sure why, despite wading through a variety of forums to find reasons.

Any insight is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

[The $link is declared elsewhere and omitted for brevity]

```
<?php
    $contributorQuery = "SELECT * FROM article";        
      $contributor_results = mysqli_query($link, $contributorQuery) 
         or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($link));
      $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($contributor_results); 

        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($contributor_results);
        if ($numrows == 0)
        {
            echo("No results found");
        }

          // store results into an array

          unset($contributorList);
          $j = 0;
          $x = 0;
          while( $contributorRecord = mysqli_fetch_array($contributor_results) )
          {  
             for($j = 0; $j < $num_fields; $j++)
             {
                $name = mysqli_query($link, $contributor_results, $j);
                $contributorList[$x][$name] = $contributorRecord[$name];
             }
             $x++;
          }
          $rowCount = count($contributorList);
          mysqli_free_result($contributor_results);             
?>
```

... I've truncated the section in which the content it outputted; but an example line would be as follows.  I can let the loop run on its own, or declare a specific result by inserting a # in the [$idx] block.

```
<?php
for( $idx = 0; $idx < $rowCount; $idx++ )
{
    echo $contributorList[$idx]['firstname'];
}
?>
```

Comment: `$name = mysqli_query($link, $contributor_results, $j);` you should be getting an error on this one. Use `mysqli_error($link)` on it and the other queries and use php's error reporting.

Comment: Well, I was looking through the source code.. Apparently you found the culprit and I missed it, like completely. @liveshotz `mysqli_query()` returns a query succession result. Not the result of the query itself.

Comment: Yes, that's all correct.  I'm getting this error; but not entirely sure the fix.  (Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given)   On the old PHP stack, If I changed it to mysql_query and removed the first $link, - it works, but mysqli has changed things, and I've hit the wall on this particular block of code.